# Cutting off the bottom of a table background when the table sizes down

Tags: css

I've been searching for two days, and trying all sorts of different options, but none of them do what I want.  I'm positive this should be possible through CSS, but haven't come across the solution yet.

We want to have a single-cell table that is 100% of the page width, but a fixed page height (although we may be able to work around a % page height.)  The table should either contain an extremely large image (that gets sized to 100% of the table width) or have a background image that does the same (so it never repeats, and just sizes up to always stay 100% of the table.

However, when the window is shrunk down, we want the table height to shrink, and "cut off" the image at either the top or bottom.

So far, I have no problem with the expansion issue, but I have yet to find a solution that shrinks the table height at all.  It either downsizes by the correct ratio for the new size of the page, or it stays exactly the same size.

Can anyone offer any suggestions?

Comment: Hey! Could you post some HTML and CSS so I can help you with your error?

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you posted a sample HTML and CSS, but in a more generic sense, I'd point you out to Flexbox - https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ and adding overflow: hidden to the DIV that contains the image.